# Login invalid after move Codeigniter website on live server

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have moved Codeigniter website from localhost to live server. When I want to login, the **login is invalid**. 
[See the Image of error here :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmwOi.png)

Comment: Please Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to get website working?

Comment: What do you mean by 'login is invalid'? What is the actual error?

Usually these problems are due to moving from a case-insensitive environment (like xampp) to a case-sensitive environment such as a linux server

Comment: Invalid Login is the error. I moved from localhost to linux server. The app is working. Just dont want to login on live server. The data for login are the same as in database.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the environment variable from development to production and it worked :)